# React component isn't updating based on the response of an async call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component card on the side of a page of my app that displays a user's current fitness track:
[image]

When the page loads the name of the track is blank because it hasn't been loaded from the server yet. However, I would expect that it would update the component and rerender as soon as the result was returned. Likewise, when you click the arrow of the component, a modal pops up asking if you are ready to advance to the next track. If you confirm, it calls a `switchTrack()` function that calls the API, and if the result is successful the user is updated and the modal closes. However, even though the track has in fact been updated, the track name doesn't refresh until you refresh the page. How do I make sure this component re-rerenders with the new text when the result comes back? (Note: You'll see I tried to force this with a reload state, but this hasn't worked).

Component Card (simplified):

```
const CurrentPlanCard = props => {
  const { open, launchModal, closeModal } = useModal(false);
  const { user } = useSelector(mapState);
  const [currentTrackName, setCurrentTrackName] = useState('');
  const [nextTrackName, setNextTrackName] = useState('');
  const [nextTrackId, setNextTrackId] = useState('');
  const [reload, setReload] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      getTrack(user.fitnessTrack)
        .then(currentTrack => {
          setCurrentTrackName(currentTrack.name);
          setNextTrackName(currentTrack?.nextTrack.name);
          setNextTrackId(currentTrack?.nextTrack._id);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
        });
    }
  }, [user, reload, setCurrentTrackName, setNextTrackName, setNextTrackId]);

  return (
    <FlexContainer justify="space-between">
      <LeftContainer flexDirection="column" justify="center">
        <Label>Current Fitness Track:</Label>
        <PlanName>{currentTrackName}</PlanName>
        <Text>Ready to move to the next stage? Switch your plan now!</Text>
      </LeftContainer>
      <RightContainer flexDirection="column" justify="center">
        <ArrowBlue onClick={launchModal} />
      </RightContainer>
      <SwitchPlanModal
        open={open}
        handleClose={closeModal}
        userId={user._id}
        currentTrackName={currentTrackName}
        nextTrackId={nextTrackId}
        nextTrackName={nextTrackName}
        reload={reload}
        setReload={setReload}
        {...props}
      />
    </FlexContainer>
  );
};
```

Modal to switch the plan:

```
const SwitchPlanModal = ({
  open,
  handleClose,
  userId,
  currentTrackName,
  nextTrackName,
  nextTrackId,
  setReload,
  reload,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const handleClick = async e => {
    try {
      if (nextTrackId) {
        await switchTrack(userId, nextTrackId);
        setReload(!reload);
        setError('');
        handleClose();
      } else {
        setError('No next track defined');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      if (err.message) {
        setError(err.message);
      } else if (err.error.message) {
        setError(err.error.message);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <StyledDialogContent>
          <Container justify="center" flexDirection="column">
            <NavBar justify="space-between" alignItems="center">
              <CloseRight>
                <CloseIcon handleClose={handleClose} />
              </CloseRight>
            </NavBar>
            <ModalBody
              justify="space-evenly"
              alignItems="center"
              flexDirection="column"
            >
              <StyledAvatar src={`${fileStorage}/AddExercise.png`} />
              <FlexContainer flexDirection="column" alignItems="center">
                <Header>Ready for the next stage?</Header>
              </FlexContainer>
              <FlexContainer flexDirection="column" alignItems="center">
                <Button
                  buttonText="Let's Go!"
                  onClick={handleClick}
                />
                <Link onClick={handleClose}>Nope, not yet</Link>
                {error && <ErrorMessage>{error}</ErrorMessage>}
              </FlexContainer>
            </ModalBody>
          </Container>
        </StyledDialogContent>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Side note: You don't need to put any of those state setters in your `useEffect` deps. The setter function from `useState` is guaranteed stable across the lifetime of the component.

Comment: eslint's exhaustive-deps rule seems to think I need them.

Comment: I use that rule, and it knows better than to insist on it for `useState` setters. Not sure why you'd be getting it saying otherwise.